# TextView button using bluetooth keyboard and voice assistant

Tags: java, android, android-layout, talkback, accessibility

I have two `TextView` in xml as buttons (Yes) and (No). I'm testing a mobile application using a bluetooth keyboard and voice assistant for blind people. What I want to happen is when the user selects the Yes button the voice assistant will say "Yes is selected" or if the user selects No it will say "No is selected".

I'm using Android Studio. This is an old mobile application that needs to be updated for blind people.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/vhr_question_yes"
    android:text="Yes"
    android:clickable="true" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/vhr_question_no"
    android:text="No"
    android:clickable="true" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add `android:contentDescription="your text to be read."` in your XML file or `vhr_question_yes.contentDescription = "your text to be read."`

```
 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/vhr_question_yes"
     android:text="Yes"
     android:contentDescription="your text to be read."
     android:clickable="true" />
```

`view.setContentDescription("your text here")` will hold text which needs to readout in case of talkback.

You can also add pause by `\n` like, "your text here \n Button \n double tap to select"

after cliked, if you need to focus on it again,then you can add,

```
view.setOnClickListener{

    //.... some action .....

    // below code will set accessibility focus again on that view.
    view.requestFocus()
    view.sendAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_FOCUSED)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may set the view state to `selected`. This way, the screen reader will notify the user a change on its state.

```
textView.setOnClickListener { view ->
    view.isSelected = true
}
```

In this case above, the screen reader will announce only that the view is selected. When the user navigates back to this view, the reader will announce again that this view is selected.

If you really need the entire text to be spoken, you may use a screen reader announcement.

```
textView.setOnClickListener {view ->
    view.isSelected = true

    (view as? TextView)?.let {
        it.announceForAccessibility("${it.text} is selected")
    }
}
```

The user may rely on consistency through the platform. When a view is selected, the reader may read as `selected, yes`. So, announcements should be used carefully.
Also, using only announcements, the selected state will not be persisted if the user comes back to this view later.